# SSIS packages not executing when run from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS project that I've been working on. I've moved to a new workstation, and when I try and run the SSIS packages from VS 2015 on this new workstation, they immediately complete with out doing any work. The progress log remains blank, and the output log only shows two lines:

```
SSIS package "C:\MyFolder\MyPackage.dtsx" starting.
SSIS package "C:\MyFolder\MyPackage.dtsx" finished: Canceled.
```

I can deploy the packages to SQL Server, and they run fine. Other SSIS projects on this workstation run without issue, and running these problem packages from other workstations also work without issue.

Anyone have any idea what might be the issue, and/or tips for how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I tried changing the TargetServerVersion from SQL Server 2012 to 2016, and doing so allowed the package to run. However, both 2012 and 2014 versions give the same results. New projects in a different solution run under 2012 without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution ended up being mis-matched versions of the Attunity Connector for Oracle.

On the new workstation, I had only installed version 4.0. Once I installed versions 3.0 and 2.0 as well, the packages began to run without issue. This is even though most of the packages I was testing didn't user the Attunity connector. Just having an MSORA connection manager in my project was enough to bring the whole thing crashing down.

Moral of the story: Even though v4.0 is required to be installed to allow the designer in VS2015 to access and use the connector/Sources/Destinations, you still need the version specific to the SSIS TargetServerVersion that you're using installed as well.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to add a comment as I had similar problem. I started the package by execute package command and no progress was visible. I checked the connections - everything fine. But still no gear icons and no progress. For me the solution was to remove the objects from /obj/Development (I created a backup in case of the problems) After that it worked fine.

Comment: This worked for me, removing all the files from ../obj/Development/
and then opening and saving the connection manager. 
I think this then repopulates the above folder, and my Execute Task then ran as expected with progress wheels, green ticks etc.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like an environmental issue. Works when targeting 2016, not when targeting 2012. New workstation, new problems.

Does the version number of SSDT match between machines?  What is your current version? And the version on the old machine?  Check [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/02/08/which-version-of-ssdt-database-projects-do-i-have-installed.aspx) on how to find SSDT version numbers.

I ask because this sound similar to MS Connect [755959](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/755959/improving-ssis-2012-canceled-status-dtsexecresult) that was resolved with a service pack update.

If your version numbers match, then [this blog](http://thinknook.com/ssis-2012-cancelled-status-issues-2012-07-29/) has great info about troubleshooting package cancellation errors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Troy. Both versions of SSDT are the same (14.0.61021.0). I had previously read that post. Unfortunately a lot of the suggestions didn't apply because it's my local workstation debugging in SSDT, rather than running on SSIS on a native SQL install. After 2 days of trying things, I have finally managed to solve it though, which I'll write up.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was fixed by changing the project Debug Option - Run64BitRuntime to False.

Right click project -> Property -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debug Option -> Run64BitRuntime

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this in VS Data tools 2012 when executing the package did not show that anything was happening.  There were no gear icons showing a task has started or green tick when a task had completed.  Later I found out that the packages were actually running and data was being extracted and loaded.  To correct this I found that if I opened the connection managers and test the connections before executing then all of execution icons worked as expected.  Thanks